# How can I filter Components of particular schema using GraphQL based on content data field e.g. date>"2023-01-01"?

Tags: content-delivery, graphql, tridion-sites, pca

```
query GenericQuery {
    items(
        filter: {publicationIds: 1, itemTypes: [COMPONENT], schema: {id: 112233} 
#want to add here some condition e.g. component.column.date>"2023-01-01"
        }
        first: 10
        after: "Mw=="
    ) {
        edges {
            node {
                itemId
                title
                lastPublishDate
                itemType
                ... on Component {
                    title
                    multiMedia
                    content(renderContent: true) {
                        ... on UntypedContent {
                            data
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            cursor
        }
    }
}
```